# Sphinx not importing all files in directory

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-apidoc

I want to create a Sphinx documentation for my Code but it won't import all files properly

The Structure looks like this:

```
├───config
├───docs
│   ├───build
│   └───source
│       └───conf.py
└───src
    ├───stages
    │   ├───stage1
    │   │   └───stage1.py
    │   ├───stage2
    │   │   └───stage2.py
    │   └───stage3
    │   │   └───stage3.py
    ├───utils
    │   ├───helper.py
    │   └───functions.py
    └───main.py
```

In conf.py I added the path:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..', '..','src'))
```

If I now run `sphinx-apidoc` it will only create the main.rst file, but not the other ones.

```
D:\project\docs>sphinx-apidoc -f -o ./ ../src --ext-autodoc
Creating file ./main.rst.
Creating file ./modules.rst.
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong and why it wont generate rst files for all the python files in the project?

Comment: Create `__init__.py` files in each of the directories to make them Python packages, and therefore importable.